# Continuity on open and closed intervals

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, definition

I will be taking Calculus I soon, and I just want to make sure I understand some concepts correctly.

So far, reading my book for Calculus I, I've encountered the definition of continuity as being defined on a *closed* interval $[a,b]$. This means that it exists at every single point in the interval including the endpoints, (meaning, that it can be approached from $a^+$, from $a^-$, from $b^+$, and from $b^-$, i.e., from both sides), correct? A polynomial would be such an example.

I looked through my book but there is no definition of continuity on an *open* interval $(a,b)$. Continuity on an open interval just means that it's approachable from only one side, either $a^-$ or $a^+$, or $b^+$ or $b^-$, but not only one of those, correct?
Is such a property the same thing as a one-sided limit? So, for example, ln would be an example of such a continuous property, since it's only defined for the positive numbers and thus can only be approached from one side?

So, then, does that mean that only a continuous function on a *closed* interval $[a,b]$ can attain a maximum/minimum value? A closed-open interval would also attain a maximum or a minimum but not both, such as $[a,b)$, correct?

sorry if these are too elementary for this website...

Comment: What is your full wording of the definition of continuity? For a function defined *only* on $[a,b]$ you simply cannot talk about $\lim_{x\to a^-}$ or $\lim_{x\to a^+}$.

Comment: but I thought that $[a,b]$ includes the endpoints and can therefore be approached from both sides

Comment: How can you approach $a$ from the left if $a$ is the left endpoint  and there is only the dark void of nothingness to its left? (Sorry, too late to edit my first comment and I don't want to delete it, but it should end in "... cannot talk about $\lim_{x\to a^-}$ or $\lim_{x\to b^+}$")

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between closed and open intervals for continuous functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201583/difference-between-closed-and-open-intervals-for-continuous-functions)

Comment: I see, thank you, but can $(a,b)$ be approached from both sides or no?@HagenvonEitzen

Comment: @user4150 Any point $x\in(a,b)$ is an inner point and can be approached from both sides. $a$ and $b$ can still be approached from one side only, but of course they are not $\in(a,b)$.